# Python Issues swapping variables into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I'm assigned to do 
Start by filling a list with 10 random numbers.
Show the list to the user.
Ask the user to pick two numbers between 1 and 10.
Swap the elements in the list that are in the two list locations the user used in #3
Check to see if the list is in order from smallest to largest.
Repeat steps 3 to 5 until done.
Thank the user for sorting the list for you.

Ive gotten to the part of assigning the user's input to a temporary box in the list but I get the error

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

and now I'm stuck. I've searched around youtube and everywhere online and can't find anything to assist me.
Heres my code:

```
numbers = [4,2,5,5,6,4,7,6,9,5]

print("Heres your current list", numbers)

print("Pick a location between 1 and 10")
num = int(input())
if num <= 10 and num >= 1:
  print("Please pick another location between 1 and 10")
  num1 = int(input())
  temp1 = list[num-1]
  temp2 = list[num1-1]
  list[num-1] = temp2
  list[num1-1] = temp1
  print(list)
```

Comment: `list` is not your list. You meant `numbers`.

Comment: `list` is the name of a python built-in type, not a variable.  First create an empty list using something like `mylist = []` or `my list = list()`.  Then use `my list` as your list name.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your list is numbers and not list. Once you make the change, your code will work.

Comment: Thank you, now im stuck on implementing a while loop to check that the list is in order and for it to keep continuing until its in order from lowest to biggest

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [4,2,5,5,6,4,7,6,9,5]

print("Heres your current list", numbers)

print("Pick a location between 1 and 10")
num = int(input())
if num <= 10 and num >= 1:
  print("Please pick another location between 1 and 10")
  num1 = int(input())
  temp1 = numbers[num-1]
  temp2 = numbers[num1-1]
  numbers[num-1] = temp2
  numbers[num1-1] = temp1
  print(numbers)
```